# Criar dialog a partir de Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

Consegui mostrar uma activity em forma de dialog, porém ela não responde ao contexto. Ao clicar no botao de editar item do meu Recycler View, uma formulário é aberto para alterações. Estou utilizando o método abaixo, porém nenhuma função do formulário executa ao fazer desta forma. Alguém pode me explicar pq isso acontece?

```
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_user);
            dialog.show();
```

Comment: Poste todo o código, por favor.

Comment: Eu consegui, apenas mudando o tema do meu XML